# Bidirectional aggregation of Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have several sub-sites where end users manage their own calendars within SP. It has been requested that users have the option to share events with another calendar that would collect events users have chosen to share.

When a users changes or deletes an event on either the main calendar or the sub-site calender both should be updated.

I have looked into the [jquery-frontier-calendar plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/) which would necessitate using SP odata service **but would prefer an OOTB solution.**

Is there anyway to handle this without third-party solutions or other plugins? If not, can anyone recommend alternative solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, I will detail the solution we came up with:

On the sub-site calendars we created a new column for each list called **Share With Master**, then each calendar has a simple workflow when an item is created with the following logic:

```
If Share With Master = Yes
{
     Email Content Manager [of the Master Calendar] a link
}
```

The link sent to the Content Manager contains each of the field values filled out in the querystring. (it might look something like /newform.aspx?Title=test%20title&Location=test%20location)

The link opens newForm.aspx of the Master Calendar and we use jQuery to populate each field of newForm.aspx so the Content Manager just clicks save and "approves" the information. To parse out the above example we would do the following:

```
    //get parameters
    var title = getURLParameter('Title');
    var location = getURLParameter('Location');

    //remove characters like %20
    var parsedTitle = decodeURI(title);
    var parsedLocation = decodeURI(location);

    //assign to fields
    $("span input[title='Title']").val(parsedTitle);
    $("span input[title='Location']").val(parsedLocation);
```

This doesn't give us the bidirectional functionality we were looking for but does allow us to easily share events between calendars. Hope this might lead someone to a better solution.